# Nesting > (greater than) in Less-CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

In LESS-CSS, this:

```
.a {
  .b {
    font-color:red;
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
.a .b {
  font-color:red;
}
```

Is there an nested equivalent of `>` ?

```
.a > .b {
  font-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does it:

```
.a {
  > .b {
    font-color:red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried doing something like `& > .b` and failed miserably. Dunno why I didn't think of the obvious way to do it - thanks.

Comment: It looks like I tried writing `> .b` in IntelliJ and got warnings from the IDE, as if it's not valid. It does compile and run, it's just an analysis bug.

Comment: An update re: CSS syntax highlighting - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122712/137537

Comment: @BoltClock: If [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions#comment328925_122712) doesn't get it fixed, nothing will.